# Several Cordapps can access to the same ledger?

Tags: blockchain, corda

I'm new to Corda and I'm still trying to understand it.

So, I already know that we can run multiple Cordapps in the same node. But the thing is that if those Cordapps can have access and update the same ledger?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can, you can have the following structure inside your project:
 1. Contracts module that defines CustomState and Custom Contract.
 2. Workflows1 module that depends on Contracts module.
 3. Workflows2 module that depends on Contracts module and Workflows1 module.
 4. Workflows1 module can have a flow that creates and modifies CustomState.
 5. Workflows2 module can have a flow that creates and modifies CustomState.
 6. Workflows2 module can call a flow from Workflows1 module.

In the above structure you have 3 CorDapps (Contracts, Workflows1, and Workflows2); they all create and modify your state.
As for if they all access the same ledger, in Corda data is shared on a need to know basis; in other words when you define your state you define the **Participants** which are the parties that will be signing the transaction and storing the resulting state.

I recommend starting here: https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts.html
Also join the Corda Slack channel (Create a Stackoverflow post and share the link there): slack.corda.net